# Changing value of variable inside vector doesn't change its value outside of vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector of class Point3D objects inside a class Figure3D. Function which changes coordinates of the Point3D object inside a vector, doesn't change coordinates of the Point3D object which is outside the vector.

Using function Figure3D::Pos() I see that the coordinates changed inside the vector after using function Figure3D::Move(), but using Point3D::full_pos() I see that the Point3D object still has its initial coordinates.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

#define PI acos(-1)

class Point3D {
public:
    Point3D()
    {
        X = 0;
        Y = 0;
        Z = 0;
    }
    Point3D(double a, double b, double c) {
        X = a;
        Y = b;
        Z = c;
    };

    void full_pos() {
        std::cout << "Coordinates of the point are: X = " << X << " Y = " << Y << " Z = " << Z << std::endl;
    }
    void Move(double dx, double dy, double dz) {
        X += dx;
        Y += dy;
        Z += dz;
    }

private:
    double X, Y, Z;
};

class Figure3D :public Point3D {
public:
    Figure3D() {
        f.reserve(10);
    }

    void AddPoint(Point3D *p) {
        f.push_back(*p);
    }

    void Move(double x, double y, double z) {
        for (auto it = f.begin(); it != f.end(); it++) {
            it->Move(x, y, z);
        }
    }
    void Pos() {
        int i = 0;
        for (auto it = f.begin(); it != f.end(); it++) {
            cout << "Position of point " << i << "  X: " << it->posX() << " Y: " << it->posY() << " Z: " << it->posZ() << std::endl;
            i++;
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<Point3D> f;
};

int main() {
    Point3D p1(1, 2, 3), p2(2, 2, 2), p3(5, 4, 7), p4(4, 9, 0);
    Figure3D f1;

    f1.AddPoint(&p1);
    f1.AddPoint(&p2);
    f1.AddPoint(&p3);
    f1.AddPoint(&p4);

    f1.Pos();
    p1.full_pos();
    f1.Move(10, 10, 10);
    f1.Pos();
    p1.full_pos();

}
```

Comment: Your observations are cotrect. The objects in the vector are independent objects. This is C++ and not Java. You are expecting objects to work like they do in Java, but C++ is not Java. What exactly is you question, it is not clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `AddPoint` function is wrong. You are passing a pointer as an argument but then you are dereferencing a pointer and storing copies of `Point3D` object into your `std::vector`. Therefore, it should be:

```cpp
void AddPoint(Point3D *p) {
    f.push_back(p);
}
```

instead of

```cpp
void AddPoint(Point3D *p) {
    f.push_back(*p);
}
```

and

```cpp
std::vector<Point3D*> f;
```

instead of

```cpp
std::vector<Point3D> f;
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you expect that the `Point3D` objects `p1` to `p4` in the `main` function to be modified as you modify the elements in the vector in the `f1` object, then they wont.

The reson is in the `AddPoint` function where you do

```
f.push_back(*p);
```

The vector stores distinct objects, not pointers or references. This together with your use of the derefernece operator makes you store a *copy* of the object inside the vector. Modifying a copy will not modify the original.